# react redux-toolkit how to fetch product by id and display the specific product?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Productget,SingleProduct } from "../Action/UserAction";

const initialState=[]
const ProductSlice =createSlice(
    {
        name: "products",
        initialState,
        extraReducers:{
            [Productget.fulfilled]:(state,{payload})=>{
                return [...payload]
            },
            [SingleProduct.fulfilled]:(state,{payload})=>{
              state.find(post=>post.id === payload.id)          
            }

        }
    }
)

const {reducer} = ProductSlice;

export default reducer
```

**React ProductDetail Component**

```
import React,{useEffect,useCallback} from 'react'
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom"
import { SingleProduct } from '../Action/UserAction';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'

function ProductDetail() {
    const {productId} = useParams();
    const product = useSelector((state)=>state.products)

    console.log(product)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const fetchDetails=useCallback(()=>{
        dispatch(SingleProduct({id:productId}))
    },[dispatch,productId])

    useEffect(()=>{
     fetchDetails()
    },[fetchDetails])
    
  return (

    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <div className="card mt-2">
          <img src={product.image} style={{width:"300px"}} className="card-img-top mx-auto mt-3" alt="market" />
          <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title">{product.title}</h5>
                                <p>{product.category}</p>
                                <p>{product.description}</p>
                                <div className="card-footer"> $ {product.price}</div>
                            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  )
}

export default ProductDetail
```

> react redux-toolkit how to fetch product by id and display the specific product??

The product detail page does not display the specific product id details. In Redux devtool the action is displaying the specific product id detail (like the image of the product and data) but the state is displaying all product detail. should the need to update the ProductDetail component